# sIFR text getting stretched vertically in IE9

Tags: sifr, internet-explorer-9

I've got a site that's using sIFR, and some of the replaced text is being stretched vertically in IE9. It's only happening in places where the text wraps 2 lines, and it fixes itself when I hover my cursor over it. The sIFR text is a link, but I'm not sure if that has any correlation.

I've tried various settings changes like fitExactly, forceClear, and forceSingleLine (though I want it to be able to wrap), and those didn't work. I've tried changing the font-size, line-height, and all other dimensions to px instead of em. `innerHTML` isn't being used anywhere on the page. It's frustrating that it works after being hovered on, but not before.

And I know you're probably thinking "use cufon or @font-face, dummy" but I'm stuck with sIFR for now. The client wants what the client wants...

Comment: same problem here Mike. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution,
if you try to hover with mouse cursor the text will display correct so..

I write few line of code to put in sifr-config.js
forcing flash reset "onReplacemment" callback only when IE9 is detected

you must use Jquery for browser detection or use another javascript way

see the link below:
http://www.voo-doo.net/robotphobia/2011/05/fix-sifr-ie9